# The fetched object at index 501 has an out of order section name 'JOURNAL OF APPLIED PHYSICS. Objects must be sorted by section name'

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, sorting, core-data

I have a database of articles with journal section names. One article is of "Journal of Applied Physics", another is of "JOURNAL OF APPLIED PHYSICS". When I use

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Journal" ascending:YES elector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```

to fetch the data, it gives me the error message.

```
The fetched object at index 501 has an out of order section name 'JOURNAL OF APPLIED PHYSICS. Objects must be sorted by section name'
```

I'm already using case insensitive compare, so why would this not work? Help?

=======
code used for fetching data =======

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Article" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:SharedMOC];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *journalSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Journal" 
                                                                     ascending:ascending 
                                                                      selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:journalSortDescriptor,  nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *a = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                    managedObjectContext:SharedMOC 
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:[self selectedSortSection]
                                                                               cacheName:cacheName];
```

Comment: Q1: How do you create your fetch request? (code please) 
Q2: Is `@"Journal"` the name of the property you're sorting by?

Comment: Thanks. In that case, is `Journal` a NSString? If `Journal` is another entity, your keypath should be `Journal.name`, for example.

Comment: Yes, Journal is a NSString. The fetching works when sort with other keypaths, just with Journal that it gives the error message. I think it's because it has two articles with the same journal but different capitalization.

Comment: Cool. Your `[self getSortDescriptor]` method... what does it return? I mean, I see you create a NSSortDescriptor and add it to `sortDescriptors` array... But you never *explicitly* set that array to the fetchRequest... Unless something like that happens in `getSortDescriptor` ?

Answer (score 1):

My intuition says that instead of:

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[self getSortDescriptor]];
```

You should write:

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: sorry. I did have a [self getSortDescriptor] method, it just I modified the code for simplification when posting here and mistakenly left that bit of code unmodified instead. Like I said in the comment, sorting works fine with other keypath like Author, Year etc. Just with Journal which had this case of capitalization difference.

Comment: Ok. Do you use `sectionIndexTitles` from NSFetchedResultsController, or did you subclass it to override that method? From the [doc](http://j.mp/kymRSJ): You create a subclass of this class if you want to customize the creation of sections and index titles. You override sectionIndexTitleForSectionName: if you want the section index title to be something other than the capitalized first letter of the section name. You override sectionIndexTitles if you want the index titles to be something other than the array created by calling sectionIndexTitleForSectionName: on all the known sections.